# Running an IIS Powershell script for a list of remote servers?

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, server

I'm trying to pull all the sites and bindings from 100+ servers that are in the same domain and have IIS running on them (already have a list of those servers in a txt file so an AD search isn't needed). This is the code that successfully pulls it from one server when I remote login and run the code on the server itself:

```
$myObject = @()
{
Foreach ($Site in get-website) 
{ 
   Foreach ($Bind in $Site.bindings.collection) 
   { 
      $myObject+=[pscustomobject]@{serverName = $vm;name=$Site.name;Protocol=$Bind.Protocol;Bindings=$Bind.BindingInformation; path=$Site.physicalPath}
   }
}
} $myObject | export-csv -Path C:\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem I have is that when I create the foreach loop listed below

```
$servers = (Get-Content results.txt)
foreach ($vm in $servers)
```

and run it at the top of the above script, the csv sheet just shows duplicates of the sites/bindings from the server I run it from, rather than pulling the results from each unique server listed in the txt file.

What would be the best way to get the results pulled from each server? I have full admin rights through my credentials and when I'm logged onto the servers, and almost all are running Windows 2012.

Comment: How are you running the remote code?

Comment: As of now I just rdp into one server with my creds and then run the powershell script on there, that's the only method I have right now but not sure if there's something else specific I should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-Website` doesn't support remote connections by itself, so you will need to use PowerShell Remoting to run it on all your servers.  Something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer (Get-Content results.txt) `
               -ScriptBlock {
                    Get-Website |
                        ForEach-Object {
                         $site = $_
                         $_.bindings.collection |
                            ForEach-Object {                           
                                [pscustomobject]@{
                                    serverName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                                    name=$site.Name
                                    Protocol=$_.Protocol
                                    Bindings=$_.BindingInformation
                                    path=$site.PhysicalPath
                                }
                            }
                        }
               } | Export-Csv -Path C:\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This works to a certain extent, but some sites have multiple bindings and the code can't find a way to break up and list all those bindings as well. Do you have an idea of how that could be fixed given the code you've mentioned?

Comment: I updated my code - did you try the current version?

Comment: Yes sorry didn't see it update, your new version works perfectly! Thank you